# use 'transform-runtime' or ‘babel-polyfill’，but can't compile some functions of array

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I hava use 'transform-runtime' with webpack, and it does work.However, some codes can't work.

```
new Array(4).fill(6);
```

my config:

```
test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           options: {
              presets: ['env'],
              plugins: ['transform-runtime']
           }
        },
```

it does't work

Comment: `entry: {
      index: ['babel-polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')]
   },`  it alse doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of `transform-runtime`. If you look at [the npm package README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) you'll see:

> NOTE: Instance methods such as "foobar".includes("foo") will not work since that would require modification of existing builtins

`transform-runtime` has does not know that `fill` in this case is `Array.prototype.fill` because it does not have any logic to see that `.fill` in this case is being called on an array object.

Comment: so,if i want use this function, should I use 'babel-polyfill'? but it also doesn't work.    entry: {
      index: ['babel-polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')]
   },

Comment: No error, but the codes are not compiled. For example, the code is 'new Array(4).fill(6);', and the result is also 'new Array(4).fill(6);'

Comment: That is expected behavior. The polyfill assigns `Array.prototype.fill`, it will not change the code that Babel outputs.